# How to make introspection from an endpoint file with apollo 2?

Tags: graphql, apollo, introspection

with apollo 1.9.2 I'm used to make **introspection** of the graphql schema **using a file** as endpoint (that way the server does not need to run).
Here the 1.9 command:

```
apollo schema:download --endpoint ./schema/def/app.graphql ./schema/lib/schema.json
```

then thanks to the generated json file I can generate the types that will be used in the client and server code:

```
apollo codegen:generate --queries ./schema/*.graphql --schema ./schema/lib/schema.json
```

Now with apollo 2, the apollo schema:download command, renamed apollo service:download, supports **only an url**. If I do not have that types the server can not start. **chicken & eggs issue**.

I did not find in the doc how to do that now.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer on gitHub

I must use a config file apollo.config.js with the following

```
module.exports = {
  service: {
    localSchemaFile: './path/to/schema.graphql',
  },
};
```

then call

```
apollo service:download -c ./path/to/apollo.config.js ./schema/lib/schema.json
```